# How to resolve parent class instance from registered child class in Asp.net core dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

**Suppose I have a class**

```
abstract class CustomContext: IdentityDbContext<AppUser, Role>{}

class TContext: CustomContext{}
```

**In the services registration**

```
services.AddDbContext<TContext>();
```

**Here in above, I can resolve the instance of TContext like below**

```
var context = ServicesCollector.Container.GetService(typeof(TContext));
```

*But somewhere in the program, I want to resolve the instance of **CustomContext**.*

Comment: CustomContext is an abstract class, you many not be able to create or resolve instance if that class. You can still do `CustomContext c = ServicesCollector.Container.GetService(typeof(TContext))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But TContext is not available in the layer where CustomContext is accessible. Like CustomContext is in parent assembly and TContext is available on child level. I have access to ServicesCollection but I am not sure how to resolve the context and then assign it to CustomContext as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the abstraction with a delegate factory that resolves the implementation.

```
services.AddScoped<CusomContext>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<TContext>());
```

That way when the abstraction is requested it will be known by the container trying to resolve it.